# Odoo gives me connection lost messages on every page load

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

My Odoo installation give me very annoying "Connection lost" with direct "Connection restored" messages during the loading phase of each page. The loading phase do not last long so it seems that there is no technical issue.

Could anyone confirm that I have no technical issue? And if that is the case how do I disable these annoying messages?

Answer (score 1):

Are you redirected to login page after error message? This problem usually happen when you use more than one user account in one browser. So, if you want to user/test with for e.g. 2 user accounts, use 2 browsers or 1 browser with incognito mode for another user.